# HTTP: Empty put on existing resource behaviour

Tags: http, webserver, put

What happens, if a a client overwrites an existing resource on my webserver with an empty PUT command (no body, content-length: 0). Will my resource's content be deleted (not the resource itself) or will nothing happen to the resource at all because nothing is there to overwrite with?

My current solution is the first one, but I am having doubts now.